# nohup with && hangs python

Tags: python, linux, pysftp

I'm using `pysftp` in python 3.7 to connect to a Linux box and issue commands.

I am running a `dask-worker` in the background.

Here's the base command to start a `dask-worker`:

```
dask-worker my_domain:8786
```

Here's the command that gets sent to the Linux box: (you can see I wrap it with `nohup` in order to allow it to continue to run, and not hang my local python process).

```
nohup dask-worker my_domain:8786 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Issuing this command works great! But I have one more thing I want to include, and I can't get it to work with this `nohup` wrapper. Maybe you can tell me why.

I want to run the `dask-worker` from a specific folder, like this:

```
cd /home/user/some_folder/ && dask-worker my_domain:8786
```

That works great, but when I wrap that in a `nohup`, it just hangs - my process on my machine issuing commands to Linux boxes doesn't move onto the next command.

So this doesn't work:

```
nohup cd /home/user/some_folder/ && dask-worker my_domain:8786 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Do you know why? Or how I can get it to spin off my `dask-worker` process at that specific location? Is there a better way of doing this than chaining Linux commands together.

Here's the reason I'm doing it this way - because I cannot get the `pysftp.chdir()` command to actually work. It doesn't change the directory on the Linux box, and maybe that's because it's Centos7, idk, but the prepackaged commands to set a working directory don't stick for me.

Thank you kindly for your attention.

Comment: just run `/home/user/some_folder/dask-worker my_domain:8786` in the background instead of cd in a separate command

Comment: The `&&` is a logical AND, and it will only execute your `dask-worker` after teh `cd` completes correctly.  Have a feeling `nohup` is blocking that return code in some way.  Try `cd /home/user/some_folder && nohup dask-worker.....`.  Also, you may want to look at running your stuff via `screen` instead of using `nohup`

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg I didn't know you could do that, I thought in order for that to work the `dask-worker` executable would have to be located in that folder

Comment: thanks @ivanivan this worked well for me `cd /home/user/some_folder && (nohup dask-worker .. > ... )`